# Ansible validate_argument_spec

Tags: ansible

I want to use ansible's `validate_argument_spec` module. Example from [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/validate_argument_spec_module.html):

```yaml
- name: verify vars needed for this task file are present when included
  ansible.builtin.validate_argument_spec:
    argument_spec: '{{required_data}}'      # <------------------
  vars:
    required_data:
      stuff:
        description: stuff
        type: str
        choices: ['who', 'knows', 'what']
        default: what
      but:
        description: i guess we need one
        type: str
        required: true
```

The docs state:

> argument_spec : A dictionary like AnsibleModule argument_spec

But I can't find the definition of `argument_spec`. What is it?

Comment: As an example, here is the argument specification (i.e. possible module options) of the `get_url` module in ansible => https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/3a1d58bc58aee4579eecc7c0fc098d790143e66c/lib/ansible/modules/get_url.py#L28

Comment: `I need the published specification, if it exists, not a link to the source code.` <= the source of specification is the source code.

Comment: `The argument_spec argument mentioned on that page is not documented anywhere` => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec

Comment: @Zeitounator Awesome! Now that's the documentation. I created a [docs request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80914) asking to point to the right place.